# Magento Bundle Product Customer Group Price

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem related to Bundle Product in Magento. I am currently working on v1.9 which has a feature called user group price. It enable us to allow different groups of customers to get different prices. For simple product the Group Price is fixed and absolute, but for bundle product it is a 'Percentage Discount'. I want to be able to define a fixed and absolute Group Price for a bundle product.

So the question is

**Is there a way to define Customer Group Price for a Bundle Product as a fixed and absolute value instead of a percentage discount?**

Comment: This might help [How to add special price for customer group in admin](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60721/how-to-add-special-price-for-customer-group-in-admin)

Comment: I think the out of the box solution is using [Catalog Price Rules](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html) or that is not possible for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same for the last couples of days, I'm working as a mangento theme developer for the last 4 years, i found that no direct feature doing that exactly but you can do it through a very good magento ext.
 1. http://www.webtexsoftware.com/customer-group-prices-magento-extension
 2. http://www.mageworx.com/customer-group-prices-magento-extension.html
 3. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-group-prices.html

Also if you didnt need to buy an extension, let's tell you that this is a very simple change, if you have a 6 months experience in mangento ext. dev. you can do it, this will help you to understand the business behind the "Price Management & Customer Groups" https://www.brightpearl.com/support/documentation/price-management-customer-groups-magento

Again your requirement is very simple: define a Customer Group Price for a Bundle Product as a fixed and absolute value instead of a percentage discount, please follow the following url: http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-bundle-product-type-part-1/

Please feel free ask me for more details.

Answer (score -2):

**Step 1:** Choose the Attribute Set 
The first step is to choose the attribute set, which is used as a template for the product record. The product in this example is based on the Default attribute set, which includes a standard of set of fields that can be used for most products.

1. On the Admin menu, go to Catalog > Manage Products.
2. In the upper-right corner of the Manage Products page, click the Add Product button.
3. In the Create Product Settings section, do the following:

Accept the “default” Attribute Set, or select another.

Set Product Type to “Simple,” and click the Continue button.

**Step 2:** Complete the Basic Information 
The basic set of required fields must be completed before the product record can be saved. The Product Information panel groups related fields by topic and the required fields are marked with a red asterisk (*).

In the Product Information panel, select General. Then, complete the required fields as follows:

1. Enter the product Name as you want it to appear in all catalog
   listings.
2. In the Description box, enter the main description that will appear
   on the Product Detail page.
3. Enter a Short Description of the product.
4. Assign a unique SKU for the product.
5. Enter the Weight of the product, which is used to calculate
   shipping.
6. Set Status to “Enabled.”
7. Set Visibility to “Catalog, Search.”

In the Product Information panel, select Prices. Then, complete the required fields as follows:

1. Enter the Price that you will charge for the product.
2. Set Tax Class to the appropriate tax classification for the product.

In the Product Information panel, select Inventory. Then, do the following:

1. If you do not need to keep track of inventory for the product, set
   Manage Stock to “No.” (Depending on the configuration, you might need to clear the Use Config Settings checkbox.)
2. If you want to keep track of inventory, set Manage Stock to “Yes.”
   Then, do the following: 
   •   In the Qty field, type the quantity of the item that is currently in stock.
   •   Set Stock Availability to “In Stock.”

To be visible in your catalog, the product must be assigned to a category. To assign the product to a category, do the following:

1. In the Product Information panel, select Categories.
2. In the category tree, click to expand the section where the item
   belongs.
3. Select the checkbox of each category where you want the product to
   appear.

If your Magento installation has multiple websites, the product must be assigned to each one where the product is available for sale. (This option appears only if multiple websites exist in the store hierarchy.) To configure the scope of the product, do the following:

1. In the Product Information panel, select Websites.
2. On the Websites tab, select the checkbox of each website where the
   product is available for sale.

After completing these steps, click the Save and Continue button.
At this point, the product should be visible on the assigned category page of your catalog. Until the product image is uploaded, a placeholder appears in its place.

**Step 3:** Complete the Remaining Product Information

Although not required, there is still more product information to complete. At the very least, you will want to upload product images and complete the meta data. In addition, you can create additional custom options.